# Upgrading OpenPGP public key on key servers?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

What is the best way to upgrade an OpenPGP key that was created 11 years ago? It's 1024-bit and is published on the key server.

I can create a new key, but what's the proper way to update the existing public key on the server?

Comment: What exactly do you want to upgrade/update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This question has a [duplicate on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/613859/102155), where I also provided an answer. As the question is a better fit here and cross-site duplicates are not allowed, I will simply be repeating it here, extending it a little bit.*

**There is no way to "upgrade" an OpenPGP key.** You will have to create a new one, and you will loose your reputation in the web of trust.

Some people I met decided to stick with a RSA 1024 primary key, but **use stronger subkeys instead** (which is easily possible without losing your reputation in the web of trust), which comes with secure day-to-day use (for encryption/signing documents with your subkeys), but might enable attackers to add and revoke certifications, subkeys and UIDs.

Think about:

- **Signing your new key with the old one**, so others could follow the signatures
- Sending a [**key transition statement**](https://we.riseup.net/assets/176898/key%20transition) to those that signed your old key; some of them might also sign your new one
- Getting your new key signed, ie. go to [**key signing parties**](https://wiki.debian.org/Keysigning)
- Revoking the old one after some time
- Using a seemingly unnecessary large key as primary key and smaller subkeys for day-to-day usage. You will never need the primary key for anything but signing other keys (which is rare) and others verifying your signatures (cheap anyway).